# Some URL patterns lose css

Tags: java, css, servlets

I'm making a simple servlet app, which is supposed to produce the same output for the following URL patterns:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/Start", "/Start/*", "/Startup", "/Startup/*"})
```

The output for the following addresses is correct:

```
http://localhost:4413/TestA/Startup
http://localhost:4413/TestA/Start
http://localhost:4413/TestA
```

However, once I try something like this:

```
http://localhost:4413/TestA/Startup/
```

or

```
http://localhost:4413/TestA/Startup/blablabla
```

The css file does not see it.

What could be wrong here?

The css links are of the form:

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="res/mc.css" type="text/css" title="cse4413"   media="screen, print"/>
```

Comment: How have you included the CSS file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the css formatting is correct for some links and does not work for others

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how you have included the CSS file. If you had included like:

```
<link href="css/style.css" />
```

Then, it won't work on directory structures. So change your code, **which is similar** to the above one like this:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" />
```

You need to provide the relative path to the domain, not the file. So that it always requests the right URL.

Comment: I added the backslash and now it does not work at all

Comment: @user3614293 Try this: `href="/TestA/res/mc.css"`.

Comment: <link rel="StyleSheet" href="res/mc.css" type="text/css" title="cse4413" media="screen, print"/> If I try to use an absolute path, like: /TestA/WebContent/res/mc.css    then it does not work at all

Comment: @user3614293 What is happening in your console? Can you have a look by using `F12`?

Comment: I'm on a mac, how do I open it?

Comment: `Cmd + Alt + J` or `Cmd + Opt + J` and reload the page.

Comment: The stylesheet http://localhost:4413/TestA/Startup/res/mc.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91323/discussion-between-user3614293-and-dhiwatdg).

Comment: Ah.. Then you need to set `webconfig.xml` to serve the right headers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by setting href to

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/res/mc.css"
```

Could anyone explain how is this different from a link of the form

project/WebContent/res/mc.css?